# error: expected expression before 'input_t'

Tags: c

So I am new to C coding and am struggling to understand what I am doing wrong. I keep getting the error mentioned in the title at the lines I have left comments on below.

```
typedef struct input{
    double x;
    double y;
    double u;
    double v;
    double rho;
} input_t; 

void read_file();

void read_file(){
    int i = 0, count = 0;
    char c;

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen ("flow_data.csv", "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Error reading file, exiting...");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        fscanf(fp, "%f %f %f %f %f", &input_t[i]->x, &input_t[i]->y, &input_t[i]->u, &input_t[i]->v, 
        &input_t[i]->rho); //getting the issue here
            i++;
    }
    for (i = 1; ; i++) {
        printf("x: %f, y: %f, u: %f, v: %f, rho: %f \n", &input_t[i]->x, &input_t[i]->y, 
        &input_t[i]->u, &input_t[i]->v, &input_t[i]->rho); //getting the issue here
    }
    for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp)) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    printf("The file has %d lines\n ", count);
}
```

I've tried looking up solutions online but am struggling to see what I am doing wrong. Any tips or guidance would be great :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to have some misunderstanding about the basics. You're using `input_t` (which is a type name) as an array. You wouldn't write `fscanf(..., &int[i]);`, would you?

Comment: What is the input file format? Your `scanf()` won't go beyond `,`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `input_t` is a type name and it cannot be used as array. You will have to declare an array variable like `input_t data[100000];` and use it like `data[i]` instead of `input_t[i]`.
- `->` operator is for accessing members of structures *that is pointed at by a pointer*. You should use `.` operator to access structures directly.
- In `scanf()`, `%f` is for reading `float` and you have to use `%lf` (add `l`) to read `double`. (It is good to use `%f` for *printing* `double` via `printf()`)
- Your usage of `while (!feof(fp))` is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). You should check if `fscanf()` is successful before doing `i++;`.
- The loop `for (i = 1; ; i++)` will run infinitely and it will lead to accessing out-of-range. You should use another variable for this loop and limit this loop upto `i` (the value of `i` before entering this loop).
- You passed `double*` for `%f` in `printf()` while `double` is expected. This will invoke *undefined behavior*. You should remove all `&`s in the arguments for `printf()`.
- The type of the variable `c` should be `int` instead of `char` because [`getc()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getc.3p.html) returns `int` and assigning that to `char` will make hard to distinguish between normal characters and `EOF`.
- You should do `fclose(fp);` after successful open of the file and after reading what is needed.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_DATA_NUM 100000

typedef struct input{
    double x;
    double y;
    double u;
    double v;
    double rho;
} input_t;

void read_file();

void read_file(){
    int i = 0, j, count = 0;
    int c;
    input_t data[MAX_DATA_NUM];

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen ("flow_data.csv", "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Error reading file, exiting...");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (i < MAX_DATA_NUM) {
        if(fscanf(fp, "%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf", &data[i].x, &data[i].y, &data[i].u, &data[i].v, 
        &data[i].rho) == 5)
            i++;
        else break;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf("x: %f, y: %f, u: %f, v: %f, rho: %f \n", data[j].x, data[j].y, 
        data[j].u, data[j].v, data[j].rho);
    }
    for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp)) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("The file has %d lines\n ", count);
}
```

Note that lines containing valid data other than the last line won't be counted because they are consumed by the data-reading part.